# Xcode and swift load default camera view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, camera

I would like to use the default camera view that you can use when opening the camera app and being able to select photos. After that, I would like to make a request and send the photo using an API. Would this be possible? Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are two different controllers, one for the camera and the other is photos.

For the camera, you can use: `UIImagePickerController`
example source code for launching the camera from your view controller:

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [presentingViewController presentViewController:_picker animated:YES completion:nil];

    //In delegate method you will receive image 
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
         //process your image here and do whatever you want to do
     }
```

The same controller can be used for selecting images too (by specifying  picker.sourceType value as UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary), from iOS 14 new API is introduced for supporting multiple image selection: `PHImagePickerViewController`.
Check this link provides sample code from apple and WWDC talk about this new API:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/selecting_photos_and_videos_in_ios